# std::regex for parsing a a string separated by colons to different groups

Tags: c++, regex

I have a config file that looks like this:

```
[sectionName]
[sectionName:subSection]
[sectoinname:sub:subsection]
[]  # This should not be matched
```

Where each string separated by a `:` character represents either a section name, or a sub section name. I want a regex (using `std::regex` in C++ 11) to parse these strings and place each section and subsection into a different group.

This is the regex that I have now:

```
([^:\[]+?)(?=:|\])
```

And it does match, but it doesn't separate into different groups, it instead matches the first section, and then adds the subsections as a suffix.

For example, on the source string `[sectionName:subSection]`:

[image]

Here is my C++ code for matching:

```
const std::smatch ConfigParser::IsSectionHeader( const std::string & aSource )
{
    std::smatch section_match;

    static const std::regex sectionReg( R"(([^:\[]+?)(?=:|\]))");
    std::regex_search( aSource, section_match, sectionReg );

    return section_match;
}
```

This is the result that I am looking for:

For test `[sectoinname:sub:subsection]`

- Full Match: `[sectoinname:sub:subsection]`
- Group 1: `sectoinname`
- Group 2: `sub`
- Group 3: `subsection`

Does anyone have any idea to group this properly? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you form total three groups where only first group is mandatory and rest are optional?

Comment: Do you have any syntax for how to do that? (Sorry, I'm not super great at regex)

Comment: Somewhat like [this](https://regex101.com/r/6mZ7Z6/1) Here the three substrings in your string will get captured in three groups while only first one is mandatory. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: It is almost what I am looking for; I updated the original question with an example of how I want the groups to look.

Comment: My regex seems to give exactly the output you expect. But as you've used `almost` word, is there something that is not desired in my solution?

Comment: Your regex doesn't separate the optional sub-sections from each other, it just places them all into one group. 

For example, `[section:subec:thirdSection]` results in the following groups: 
* Group 1: `section:subsec:thirdSection`
* Group 2: `subsec:thirdSection`
* Group 3: `thirdSection`

When it **should** result in :
* Group 1: `section`
* Group 2: `subsec`
* Group 3: `thirdSection`

Comment: No no, Check my link again. I've deleted one of my previous comment where group1 was containing all content but I've corrected that and posted my comment again. Can you check the link again in my comment where each group only contains the desired item instead of all.

Comment: The updated link does work! Sorry about that, didn't notice that you edited the link. If you post that regex as the answer I can approve

Comment: Actually that's my mistake, I should've mentioned that in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex which groups the required data into three groups, while making only the first one as mandatory and other groups appear as nested and optional.

```
\[(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(?::(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(?::([a-zA-Z]+))?))?)\]
```

**Explanation:**

- `\[` - Starts capturing the pattern with literal `[`
- `(?:` - Starts a non-grouping pattern
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - Captures the first alphabetical text and places them in group1
- `(?::(?:([a-zA-Z]+)(?::([a-zA-Z]+))?))?` - This part is a doubly nested pattern that is colon separated and places the two alphabetic text in group2 and group3 both of which are optional as the non-capturing group is followed by `?`
- `)\]` - Closes the non-grouping pattern followed by literal `]`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mZ7Z6/1)**